# VBA Populating column with value from Len formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column in my spreadsheet called 'GRIDREF' that contains string values of variable length. I would like to add an additional column in the same sheet called 'Precision' and populate it with values depending on the value returned for the length of the string GRID REF. The first two subs in my VBA code seem to be ok. But not the last, and I wondered why?

Initial table example before macro:

```
ANIMAL  GRIDREF
CAT     NZ3344
RABBIT  NZ5566
CHIMP   NZ45
TURTLE  NZ22345
```

Desired Outcome;

```
ANIMAL  PRECISION   GRIDREF
CAT      1 Km      NZ3344
RABBIT   1 Km      NZ5566
CHIMP    Not 1 Km  NZ45
TURTLE   Not 1 Km  NZ22345
```

Actual Outcome

```
ANIMAL  PRECISION   GRIDREF
CAT                NZ3344
RABBIT             NZ5566
CHIMP              NZ45
TURTLE             NZ22345
```

My code is as follows:

```
'Insert Col
Sub InsertColumn()
    Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight,
    CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("B1").Value = "Precision"
End Sub

Sub Definecolnames()

    lastUsedColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For col = 1 To lastUsedColumn
        If Cells(1, col).Value = "GRIDREF" Then
            GR = col
        End If
        If Cells(1, col).Value = "Precision" Then
            Precision = col
        End If
    Next col

End Sub

Sub Populate()
    last = Cells(Rows.Count, GR).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = last To 1 Step -1
        If Len(Cells(i, GR).Value) = 6 Then
            Cells(i, Precision).Value = "1 km"
        ElseIf Len(Cells(1, GR.Value) <> 6 Then
            Cells(i, Precision).Value = "not 1km"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52187192/edit) your post to add some sample data, your expected output and how it differs from what you get at the moment?

Comment: The code above doesn't compile. Is this the actual code you're using?

Comment: Here `ElseIf Len(Cells(1, GR.Value) <> 6 Then` you are always looking at Row 1. No matter what he value in cell you are picking up and using it's column number.  The conitional setting for `GR = col` is just a sham. Actually non of your procs are working.

Comment: For future reference, please use something like [this tool](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation) to ensure proper indentation - it makes code so much easier to look at.

Comment: Thank you @Xabier for your helpful reply :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will do what you expect it to, there was a typo on the following line `ElseIf Len(Cells(1, GR.Value) <> 6 Then`, I've also re-wrote some of your code, so instead of looping with a For Loop, I used the .Find method to find the relevant columns:

```
Sub InsertDefinePopulate()

Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("B1").Value = "Precision"

Set GRFound = Range("1:1").Find(What:="GRIDREF", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not GRFound Is Nothing Then GR = GRFound.Column

Set PrecisionFound = Range("1:1").Find(What:="Precision", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not PrecisionFound Is Nothing Then Precision = PrecisionFound.Column

last = Cells(Rows.Count, GR).End(xlUp).Row

For i = last To 1 Step -1
    If Len(Cells(i, GR).Value) = 6 Then
        Cells(i, Precision).Value = "1 km"
    ElseIf Len(Cells(i, GR)) <> 6 Then
        Cells(i, Precision).Value = "not 1km"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```